# Search Patterns in Fixed File Length file and output entrire line

Tags: unix

I need a command to look for a pattern in specific columns in a fixed length file and output the entire line to a different file.

Example"
File1

```
2345abcdef450022677

1234sdfght350022677

3456abcdef350022677
```

I need extract the lines if column 5 to 10 = abcdef and column 15 to 16 = 22.

I want the output file to have the following data

```
2345abcdef450022677

3456abcdef350022677
```

I can use the cut command with grep to find the pattern but not sure how to output the entire line

Comment: You're looking for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed:

```
sed -r '/^.{4}abcdef.{4}22/!d' inputfile > outputfile
```

This finds lines starting with any four characters `^.{4}`, followed by `abcdef`, followed by any 4 characters `.{4}`, followed by `22`, then it deletes lines that don't match `!d`.